# Count Aggregate in FetchXML report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2016

Trying to create a FetchXML report for CRM 2016 using VS2012 following instructions here:  [Create a new report using SQL Server Data Tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531151.aspx).  I want to simply find a count of cases created between two dates.

The instructions talk about copy/pasting downloaded FetchXML from the CRM Advanced find process.

FetchXML generated by the Advanced Find process to list all Cases (by ticketnumber):

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="incident">
    <attribute name="incidentid" />
    <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
    <order attribute="ticketnumber" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="2015-07-01" />
        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="2016-06-30" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I can't find a way to aggregate with Advanced Find, but instructions here:  [Use FetchXML aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx) seem to indicate a couple of attribute changes to the XML is all that is necessary.

So, I changed my FetchXML in notepad++ to:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" aggregate="true" >
      <entity name="incident">
        <attribute name="incidentid" />
        <attribute name="ticketnumber" aggregate="count" alias="casecount" />
        <order attribute="ticketnumber" descending="false" />
        <filter type="and">
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="2015-07-01" />
            <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="2016-06-30" />
          </filter>
        </filter>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

This results in an error:
[image: Fetch->Sandbox Error]

Either I'm doing something wrong, or that FetchXML Aggregation page is incorrect.

Can someone show me how to create a fetchXML report that counts cases opened between two dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select an attribute (`incidentid`) while at the same time doing aggregation.

Additionally, applying ordering does not make sense when you are aggregating.

I have removed those two lines, after which the FetchXML is able to run:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" aggregate="true" >
  <entity name="incident">
    <attribute name="ticketnumber" aggregate="count" alias="casecount" />
    <filter type="and">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="2015-07-01" />
        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-before" value="2016-06-30" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

As a side-note, you might want to use the FetchXml Tester in [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) for quickly being able to edit and execute FetchXML.

Comment: Thank you.  This did the job, once I recreated the report in VS.  I'm not sure how the incidentid was selected, I just used the advanced find and it gave me those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for order by clause

`<order alias="casecount" descending="true" />`